# ZF2 PHPUnit - Testing Controller

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

So I decided to dive into PHPUnit and I've been reading a lot of documentation and finding examples all over the place but I'm stuck on a single error that I simply cannot get passed. I'm hoping someone can help point out what I am missing.

The current documentation I am using can be found [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/unittesting.html)

Here is what my project tree looks like:

[image: Project Tree]

**LoginControllerTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace LoginTest\Controller;

use LoginTest\Bootstrap;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

/**
 * Class TestControllerTest
 *
 * @package LoginTest\Controller
 */
class TestControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    /**
     * Setup
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setTraceError(true);

        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            Bootstrap::getConfig()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Index Action
     */
    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $authenticationService = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService')
                                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                      ->getMock();

        $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                              ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                              ->getMock();

        $functionDates = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Dates')
                              ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                              ->getMock();

        $functionEncryption = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Encryption')
                                   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                   ->getMock();

        $functionIpaddress = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress')
                                  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                  ->getMock();

        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();

        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
            $authenticationService
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
            $entityManager
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Dates',
            $functionDates
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Encryption',
            $functionEncryption
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress',
            $functionIpaddress
        );

        $this->dispatch('/');

        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('Login');
        $this->assertControllerName('Login\Controller\Login');
        $this->assertControllerClass('LoginController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('login');
    }

    /**
     * Index Action (Copy)
     */
    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessedCopy()
    {
        $authenticationService = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService')
                                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                      ->getMock();

        $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                              ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                              ->getMock();

        $functionDates = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Dates')
                              ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                              ->getMock();

        $functionEncryption = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Encryption')
                                   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                   ->getMock();

        $functionIpaddress = $this->getMockBuilder('OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress')
                                  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                  ->getMock();

        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();

        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
            $authenticationService
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
            $entityManager
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Dates',
            $functionDates
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Encryption',
            $functionEncryption
        );

        $serviceManager->setService(
            'OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress',
            $functionIpaddress
        );

        $this->dispatch('/');

        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('Login');
        $this->assertControllerName('Login\Controller\Login');
        $this->assertControllerClass('LoginController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('login');
    }
}
```

When I run `phpunit` I am receiving the expected results.

However when I copy the exact same test and change the function name and re-run `phpunit` I am receiving the following output:

```
PHPUnit 4.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /vhosts/admin-application/vendor/otwebsoft/admin-login/test/phpunit.xml

.E

Time: 471 ms, Memory: 3.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) LoginTest\Controller\TestControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessedCopy
Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given.

/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php:342
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php:127
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:174
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:96
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:115
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:252
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:164
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:178
/vhosts/admin-application/vendor/otwebsoft/admin-login/test/LoginTest/Controller/TestControllerTest.php:115
phar:///usr/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
phar:///usr/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 5, Errors: 1.
```

Line 115 is:

```
$serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
```

I'm currently running Zend Framework 2.3.4 and PHPUnit 4.4.5

If I can supply any other information please let me know. I've scoured pages after pages on Google and I'm at a complete loss at the moment.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

I decided to redo my entire project using composer to install ZF2 and my modules. I followed the ZF2 Unit Testing guide to setup my project line for line.

**Edit 2**

I'm not sure why but if I comment out this line in the Bootstrap

```
$serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
```

Then the tests run without problems any problems. When I re-enable that single line of code that's when it complains about merging configs. As we can see from the PHPUnit error, the first test did run just fine, but the second did not.

I honestly do not understand what the `loadModules()` function has to do with anything but if disabling that single line is all I have to do that is fine. I just find it strange that it's causing the problem.

Comment: The error message is telling you that a configuration method returned something that wasn't traversable (eg: an array).  Do any of the modules you're loading have a `Module::getConfig` method that is returning a non-array?  Or, if you're loading configuration from any files during bootstrap do those not return an array?

Comment: All my modules currently do return a config array but I'm not sure about the bootstrap. The thought hadn't even crossed my mind that it would pose a problem but I'll certainly check this out.

Comment: I've cleaned up my question in hopes it better explains my situation. @AdamLundrigan I also ensured that everything being returned does return an array.

Comment: What's at Line 160 of /vhosts/admin-application/vendor/otwebsoft/admin-login/test/LoginTest/Controller/TestControllerTest.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

My `PHPUnit` setup is correct however, in the `config/module.config.php` file I had:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include_once __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

and it should have been:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

I assume this explains why the first test would run but not the remaining tests.

This also resolved the problem by having to disable the `loadModules()` function. It is now re-enabled and things appear to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mistaking in PHP.

Your Code:

```
/**
 * Setup
 */
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setApplicationConfig(
        Bootstrap::config()
    );

    parent::setUp();
}
```

Doesn't call autoload anywhere.
There isn't a rule that autoload function will be trigger automatically

Choose 1, change setUp:

```
/**
 * Setup
 */
public function setUp()
{
    Bootstrap::autoload()

    $this->setApplicationConfig(
        Bootstrap::config()
    );

    parent::setUp();
}
```

There is another alternatives, goes this way.

Comment: Actually the autoload is being called inside of the Bootstrap. I gave you option a try anyways and there are many random errors.